# After enable html5 mode it didn't show rating svg icon fill color

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, svg

I'm using star-rating-svg in angular project. this plugin working fine without enabling html5 mode and when enable html5 mode it didn't show rating svg icon fill color

[image]

after enable html5 mode

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

filling start not show like empty star

[image]

Comment: any errors you get?

Comment: no i dont get any error

Comment: Could you please share plunkr

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `<base>` tags. chrome bug when use base tag svg images aren't storing correct. I'm using this line of code. this code works fine.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
```